# Is there a theoretical maximum speed for wind?

Tags: geophysics, kinetic-theory, meteorology

What we call *wind* is actually molecules moving into an area of lower particle density due to their thermal motion. A lower particle density offers less collisions (resistance), so more molecules move towards lower particle density than in another direction, which creates a flow.

When wind is microscopically based on thermal motion, wind could not blow faster than the thermal speed of molecules it is composed of. So, within the atmosphere at 293,15 K wind speed has an upper limit of about 450 m/s, which means there can't be any wind blowing faster than that.

Is this correct?

Edit: I am talking about atmospheric wind, not artificial wind in wind tunnels or the like.

Comment: Wind is caused by differences in the atmospheric pressure. When a difference in atmospheric pressure exists, air moves from the higher to the lower pressure area, resulting in winds of various speeds, it is not caused by microscopical thermal motion

Comment: @brucesmitherson: What is atmospheric pressure? Impacts of moving molecules. I don't see an argument in your comment why the microscopic description should be wrong.

Comment: "When wind is microscopically based on thermal motion, wind could not blow faster than the thermal speed of molecules it is composed of." Wrong. Molecules of air in wind are a bit like passengers on a train. The train moves at a net speed as do its passengers but the passengers can walk about, even run or jump up and down. The speed limit of wind is essentially the speed of light, as no particles part of the wind can travel faster than light.

Comment: the macroscopic motion is unrelated to the internal motion of the molecules, think for instance of a  moving balloon: the thermal motion of the molecules inside is unrelated to the motion of the balloon's center of mass.

Comment: same with big chunks of moving air

Comment: @Gert: Could you please elaborate more on the "train" you are talking about? I can't imagine what the train should be in the real world.

Comment: @brucesmitherson: You haven't responded to the microscopic description. Let's take an analogy: Imagine a closed container with a pressure of 2 bar. There is a higher particle density inside the container than outside of it. When you open the container, molecules move out. They move out not because they get accelerated, they move out due to their thermal motion because outside is a lower particle density. But if you say that they do get accelerated then please explain how and why on a MICROSCOPIC level.

Comment: @Chris: in the analogy the large mass of moving air called 'wind' is the train's carriage. The air molecules are the passengers. The passengers can move freely along the train, walk, run, jump up and down, whatever. Similarly the *thermal* movement of molecules in the wind is independent from the *bulk* movement of air.

Comment: limit: well, it also depends of what you call "wind" or what you consider is not. e.g. would a shockwave count ? (e.g. when an asteroid hit Earth). Would the velocity field inside a tornado count ?

Comment: Does the solar wind count?  That flows at supersonic speeds...